# Is it possible to rotate a certain part of a graph in python by 90, 180 and 270 degrees?

Tags: python, graph, rotation

I'm currently writing a code where I should implement the pivot algorithm. This means that I have to rotate a part of the graph either 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

The code uses lists for both x- and y coordinates, and the graph needs to be rotated from the k-th entries of both lists (where k is any integer between 0 and the length of the list) and the endpoints of both lists.

Is there any way to do this and if so, how?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) example of what you have so far, and what you expect as result.

Comment: The answer will depend almost entirely on how you're creating the graph (i.e. the library/module are you using) and the code that's doing it. Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: To rotate a point [X,Y] around the origin [0,0], see rotation matrices (linear algebra). For right angles in 2D, these are 2x2 matrices with only 3 possible numbers -1, 0, 1 in them. To rotate around a different point, just move the coordinates to place the central point to [0,0], apply the rotation, and move it back. To get better answers, please improve your question, be more specific, show your code, describe the problem you are facing.